# Spring Cloud Stream Consumer not consuming messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Below is the code of Consumer Service which consumes from kafka topic loc-4. The producer service is producing the messages, I can see in the console, but not able to log the messages and do any processing. I am using spring-cloud-stream and spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka dependencies.

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class LocationFiveService {

    @Autowired
    private LocationFiveRepo repo;

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<TagLocation>> consumerLast() {
       
        return message -> {
            TagLocation payload = message.getPayload();
            processtags(payload);
            System.out.println("Consuming the tag message: " + payload);
        };
    }

    private void processtags(TagLocation payload) {
        Optional<TagLocation> findTagById = repo.findById(payload.getTagId());
        if(!findTagById.isEmpty()) {
            TagLocation tagLocationDb = findTagById.get();
            tagLocationDb.setTagStatus(true);
            tagLocationDb.setTagTimeStamp(LocalDateTime.now());
            repo.save(tagLocationDb);
        }
    }
}
```

My application.yml

```yaml
server:
  port: 8085

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username: root
    password: root
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true  
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: consumer
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: xx.xx.xx.xx:9092
      bindings:
        consumer-in-0:
          destination: loc-4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your binding configuration is wrong. Your Consumer bean name is `consumerLast` yet your binding is configured for `consumer-in-0` when it should be `consumerLast-in-0`.

For more details on binding names read this - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_binding_and_binding_names